# Batch processing in Adobe Audition for deleting silence

Tags: automation, silence, adobe-audition

I have a folder with hundreds of audio lectures that I would like to process in batch. I'm trying to remove the silent parts, and have found Audition to be very good at this. The thing is I can't select multiple files to do this, I can only do it in the waveform editor in Diagnostics==>Delete Silence one at a time. Is there something I'm missing? Any program is fine, I just need to have a program that can process a batch of mp3s and apply this process. I'm running OSX, but also have a virtual machine with Windows 10 if it's necessary.

http://sox.sourceforge.net I found this as a possible solution, but it would be really neat to use Audition somehow (maybe it can be scripted?) or something with a GUI for the settings. It's really tedious to process these files one by one...

Comment: Sox is by far the best solution. You can write a batch file to do all your files at once.